# Pricing configurable options value depending on another value

Tags: php, whmcs

I have a record in the `configurable options` called `Accounts` which is a select menu contains `[10,50,100,200]` and another record called `Points` and I want to set a price for the `Points` to be like `Points Price + ( Accounts Count * 0.25)` But I only can set a fixed price not dynamic one.
Is what am I seeking is doable??

Answer (score 0):

According to an [answer](http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?105491-Pricing-configurable-options-value-depending-on-another-value&p=434195#post434195) in WHMCS Forums, That is not currently possible so I have to write my own Module to do what I want.